# class that uses a factory that returns generic interface<T> resolves a list of T but not just T

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following setup. I have an `AbstractFetcher<T>` that is implemented by `StringFetcher`. Then I have a factory that returns `AbstractFetcher`s based on input.. here `OneClass` is using the `AbstractFactoryFetcher`. In the method `doSomething` I get compiler error for the second line but not the first one! In other words the `fetchMany()` is compiling fine! What is the reason this is happening? How can the signatures be changed even with the use of generic method hints so that no casting is needed? My ultimate goal is to decouple OneClass from knowing anything about the concrete fetchers being returnt so it can be deployed / compiled separately even if there are changes on FetcherFactory.

```
public interface AbstractFetcher<T> {
    T fetchOne();
    List<T> fetchMany();
}

public class StringFetcher implements  AbstractFetcher<String> {

    @Override
    public String fetchOne() {
        return "a string"
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> fetchMany() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("String 1");
        list.add("String 2");
        return list;
    }
}

public interface AbstractFactoryFetcher {
    public AbstractFactoryFetcher make(String type);
}

public class FetcherFactory implements AbstractFactoryFetcher {
    public AbstractFetcher make(String type) {
        if (type.equals("String")) {
            return new StringFetcher();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class OneClass {
    FetcherFactory factory;
    public OneClass(FetcherFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        List<String> list = factory.make("String").fetchMany();
        String one = factory.make("String").fetchOne(); //compiler error Required: String, Found: Object
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you know you want a `Fetcher<String>` why not just `new StringFetcher()` or `makeStringFetcher()`? More generally, to create a `Fetcher<T>` use a `FetcherFactory<T>`.

Comment: One reason that I am sacrificing type safety by using make(String input) instead of `makeStringFetcher()` is to to reduce coupling and enable independent deployability (as suggested by clean coder videos). My actual scenario is of course more complicated than this one. For your later suggestion then I will have a factory for each of the types of elements I create which I believe is not correct..this will increase my dependencies and private variables to 22x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well still there is a casting but in factory:

```
public class FetcherFactory {
        public <T> AbstractFetcher<T> make(Class<T> type) {
            if (type.equals(String.class)) {
                return (AbstractFetcher<T>) new StringFetcher();
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can call like:

```
public void doSomething() {
    List<String> list = factory.make(String.class).fetchMany();
    String one = factory.make(String.class).fetchOne(); 
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.. This way the AbstractFetcherFactory never changes and it has a single signature so there is no dependency even on the number of things that are being returned.. so essentially `AbstractFetcherFactory` never need to be compiled again, neither anything that depends on it!

Comment: There's no call for reflection here.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `AbstractFetcher` as a raw type in `doSomething`, that means that the erasure of it's methods is used:

```
Object fetchOne();
List fetchMany();
```

While a `List` can be converted to a `List<String>` (with an unchecked warning). Object can not be converted to `String`.

Preferably, you'd have strongly typed factory:

```
public AbstractFetcher<String> makeStringFetcher() {
    return new StringFetcher();
}
```

You're attempting to use the return value as an `AbstractFetcher<String>`, which implies that you know the `type` string at compile time any ways.

Generics are a compile time thing, and there is no way for the compiler to know the runtime value of the `type` string. So you can't have generic type safety in that case.

Comment: I had it this way you suggest and I try to move away from it.. I am trying to implement Abstract Factory pattern properly using a single method make().. I am willing to sacrifice type safety for independent deployability as described in the clean coders videos/books.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis An abstract factory can be strongly type too. Just look at the [wikipedia example](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abstract_factory_pattern) for instance:

Comment: the way you suggest still leaves a dependency on the number of different fetchers being returned.. so whenever a new fetcher is added the factory is changes and its interface causing everything that uses this interface to be recompiled..

Comment: @MichailMichailidis That can be a good thing too. If you were to remove support for one of the fetchers the code using that fetcher wouldn't know the difference and would break at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK to pass in a `Class<X>` instead of a string parameter to the factory, there is a way to achieve this without any casting, but it requires reflection to make it work.

Implement `FetcherFactory` like so:

```
public class FetcherFactory {
  public <T, U extends AbstractFetcher<T>> AbstractFetcher<T> make(Class<U> type) {
    try {
      return type.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use it at the call site like so:

```
public class OneClass {
  FetcherFactory factory;
  public OneClass(FetcherFactory factory) {
    this.factory = factory;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    List<String> list = factory.make(StringFetcher.class).fetchMany();
    String one = factory.make(StringFetcher.class).fetchOne();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! reflection! hm.. apart from this shortcoming what is the gain compared to HRgiger's answer?

Comment: Not much, but no casting and no need to add new cases for new types.

Comment: But doesn't requiring the user of the fetcher factory to specify which concrete type of fetcher should be created by the factory somehow defeat the purpose of the factory? In HRigger's solution the user has only to specify which type of object the created fetcher should be able to fetch and the factory is allowed to decide which concrete type of fetcher it creates.

Comment: @Calculator, sure, it depends on how the token (parameter `type`) for specifying the factory type is obtained.